# how to use data from table 1 and divide by specific data in table 2 within sql

Tags: sql, join, union

I am writing a query where it pulls the previous months total # of renewals from table 1 and then divides it by the national average of working business days for that specific month from table 2 (both tables are in the same sever & database).

I have the queries for the above statement, I just do not know how to connect them.

The query is essentially: Total # of Renewal Volume for month A / # of business days in month A

From my understanding I need to make sure that the data in columns 'YR' and 'MTH' in table 1 match columns 'cal_month' and 'cal_year' in table 2. If so it would then take the total # of renewals in the 'volumes' column in table 1 and divide it by the # of business days in the 'national_avg' column in table 2.

```
select volume, YR, MTH
from example.dbo.table1
where month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
      and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
group by MTH, YR


select cal_month, cal_year, National_Avg
from example.dbo.table2
where cal_month = DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(month,-1,current_timestamp))
    AND cal_year  = DATENAME(yyyy, DATEADD(month,-1,current_timestamp))
```

Example

Table 1

```
Volume / MTH / YR

200   / 2 / 2018
```

Table 2

```
cal_month / cal_year / national_avg

February / 2018 / 22
```

Expected result:

9.09

I am fairly new with sql, I think I got the logic correct I'm just having trouble writing the correct syntax. I was thinking of using a temptable, I just dont have experience with one. Thank you

Comment: What database are you using? Can you add some example data?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Okay I added sample data, don't know how to format a table on here.  thanks

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data and also the expected result!

Comment: Okay I did, basically Volumes / National_avg given that the year & month match. The rows are being filtered within my query  for the specific month and year so I cannot provide more rows

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap up both queries as subqueries and join on the necessary fields like below.  Then you can easily create your new column by dividing volume by nationalavg

```
select *, volume/ case when National_Avg=0 then 1 else National_Avg end NewColumn  from (select volume, YR, MTH
from example.dbo.table1
where month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
      and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
group by MTH, YR)a
join
(select cal_month, cal_year, National_Avg
from example.dbo.table2
where cal_month = DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(month,-1,current_timestamp))
    AND cal_year  = DATENAME(yyyy, DATEADD(month,-1,current_timestamp)))b
    on a.yr=b.cal_year and a.mth=b.cal_month
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, what does the case statement mean? "when National_Avg = 0 then 1... "

Comment: Stops you from dividing by zero which is illegal and will give you an error.  The case statement basically says if the denominator here is zero replace it with 1 else keep the original value.  You can adjust this however you'd like but make sure you put something there in case zero comes along.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is `cross join`:

```
select . . .
from (select t1.volume, t1.YR, t1.MTH
      from example.dbo.table1 t1
      where datecompleted >= dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(current_timestamp), current_timestamp)) and
            datecompleted < dateadd(day, 1 - day(current_timestamp), current_timestamp)
     ) v cross join
     (select cal_month, t2.cal_year, t2.National_Avg
      from example.dbo.table2 t2
      where t2.cal_month = DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month,-1, current_timestamp)) and
            t2.cal_year  = DATENAME(year, DATEADD(month, -1, current_timestamp))
     ) n;
```

Note that I changed the date logic for the first subquery.  It is better to not use function calls or type casts on the columns, because that can prevent the use of indexes.

I would recommend that you use the same time identifier in each table -- such as a date column for the beginning of the period.